# Why is my aperture locked?

Tags: canon, camera-settings, canon-80d

I have a Canon 80D. I used the built-in pop-up flash yesterday and now when I try to change the aperture it says lock and it turns red. I’ve put the camera into P,A,S,M modes with the same results. The only way to change my aperture is to press the Q button and manually choose the aperture. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Multifunction Lock switch at the bottom right of the back panel allows you to lock the main dial, quick control dial, multi-controller, and touch control, from accidental changes. When in the 'up' position, the controls do not change any settings, "Lock" will be displayed in live view, and 'L' will be displayed in the view finder and top screen.

You can selectively choose whether each of those 4 controls are affected by the Multifunction Lock switch in the settings menu. See [p. 54 of the 80D User Manual](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/4/0300022454/03/eos80d-im3-en.pdf#page=54) for details.